# Unity game with post-processing works fine when I play it by myself, but when other people play it game is too bright

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, post-processing

So, on my PC it is normal. When I try to record it, it becomes brighter on video as well as on other people's computers. I used Vignette, Bloom and Ambient Occlusion. How to make the game look the same on any device?

How it should look like
[image: How it should look like]

How it actually looks like
[image: How it actually looks like]

Comment: just to make sure it really IS an issue with the postprocessing: did you try disabeling all PP? was there still a difference in brightness?

Comment: How did you capture the "How it should look like" image and how did you capture the "How it actually looks like" image?

Comment: @Wyck In "how it actually looks like" I used OBS to capture gameplay(it has the same brightness as on other computers). In "how it should look like" I just made a screenshot of my screen using LightShot.

Comment: @pixlhero oh, should check that out

Comment: @pixlhero Woah, yeah. It turns out that even without PP there is a distinction in brightness. What could cause this?

Comment: @pixlhero I just tested all my other unity projects on other devices. They are ALL brighter than they should be! Now I don't know what to do with it...

Comment: @pixlhero I just sent this project to my friend and on his laptop brightness of the game is the same as it should be. On my two laptops brightness is higher than it should be. I just don't understand how it works

Comment: Well, there are a lot of possibilities. But possibly it's something that is set by the user though the OS. For example night mode, or similar.